# Is this sentence fragment?

Tags: grammar

I would like to ask a question with regards to sentence fragment. So here is the sentence I have issue with:

Mike doesn't know.

I think the sentence above is not a fragment although it lacks a complete thought. Is my evaluation correct? I would be glad if you could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that it is a sentence and not a fragment.

'Mike doesn't know.'

Subject= 'Mike'

Predicate= 'doesn't know'; main verb 'know' is preceded by auxiliary verb 'doesn't '

There is a complete thought.